# Rendering js.erb output raw javascript code

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am doing this simple ajax call in my rails app like this.

```
<%= link_to 'test_js', '#', class: "ajax_call"  %>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(".ajax_call").on("click", function () {
   $.ajax({
          url: "<%= users_get_details_path %>",
          dataType: 'script',
          type: 'GET'
        });
  })
</script>
```

and my controller action looks like this

```
def get_details
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js {}
    end
  end
```

**get_details.js.erb**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
console.log('working!!!');
alert("working!!!");
});
```

This does not give any alert or text in the console or any error instead it outputs the whole js.erb raw content in the dom console. I don't understand what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: Try to put only `alert("working!!!");`, It doesn't require the `$(document).ready(function ()` function.

Comment: @asdfkjasdfjk Try to put plain path in  url . e.g url:  "users/get_details"

Comment: After trying several things same code is working now. Probably it was cache problem or something. But suddenly same code started working

Answer (score 0):

If you want get console log or alert when finish ajax request, you can do like below:

```
<%= link_to 'test_js', '#', class: "ajax_call"  %>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".ajax_call").on("click", function () {
       $.ajax({
          url: "<%= users_get_details_path %>",
          dataType: 'script',
          type: 'GET',
          success: function(data){
             console.log('working!!!');
             alert("working!!!");
             console.log(data);
          }
       });
  })
</script>
```

I add `console.log(data)` to log what data you got from `users_get_details_path`.

Hope it helps.